# Stop Chrome from fetching favicon for a specific bookmark

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, favicon

I have a URL bookmarked in Chrome. Once in a while, Chrome requests `GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0` from that server.

I do not want Chrome to access that server unnecessarily, at least unless I specifically open that bookmark.

How do I disable these favicon requests? Can I force a given bookmark not to have any favicon, or use a local file instead?

What I found was a suggestion to modify the `<head>` of that page accordingly, but that won't work because to see those instructions the browser would have to fetch the page first, and the solution I need has to be somehow local.

**UPDATE**: needs to work from the Bookmarks Bar on `chrome://newtab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not work directly on `chrome://` protocol sites such as `chrome://newtab`, whether in bookmarklets or in extensions without proper permissions, due to security reasons.

There's an HTML workaround though, I don't know why it's allowed - likely because it's executed on a new page, but not like this kind of URLs are very secure either:

```
data:text/html,<script>window.location.href='http://example.com'</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark `javascript:void(location="http://example.com")` instead.

Comment: Great idea! But it doesn't work on the new tab page (`chrome://newtab`). Even the simplest `javascript:(function(){alert('this is a test');})();` doesn't work there (does when triggered on regular pages though)